# How to interact with a TPM at boot time?

Tags: linux, boot, tpm

I'm currently experimenting with a minimal linux system built through [Buildroot](https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot) in which I want to use a TPM to derive a key and make some measurements during boot. At best, this would happen in the bootrom (i.e. the first code that's executed after power is supplied to the system) so that all boot components can be properly measured.

Generally, Buildroot uses U-Boot, which has TPM drivers available so I could use them there and, of course, inside the Linux Kernel. But as the TPM device first needs to be activated somewhere in the bootloader code (i.e. U-Boot), does this mark the border of "unmeasureable" code?

Can I somehow interact with the TPM from the bootrom and if not, how do real secure boot implementations deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On regular PCs, it's always the "platform" (i.e. bootrom or firmware authenticated by the bootrom) – **not** the bootloader – that calls TPM2_Startup. At the point where the bootloader can measure the OS files, the TPM is already running and already has both the firmware and the bootloader itself measured to it (the former into PCR 0, the latter into PCR 4). Take a look at the [TCG PC Client Specific Platform Firmware Profile Specification](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/resource/pc-client-specific-platform-firmware-profile-specification/), where it mentions "SRTM".

So normally on a PC you would have the system firmware (which is nowadays often digitally signed and verified by the CPU) measuring itself into PCR 0, then the firmware measuring every EFI executable into PCR 4 (bootloader, Linux EFI stub, etc) – and their Secure Boot certificates into PCR 7 if SB is in use – and only then the bootloader measuring the OS kernel. Measurements of the Linux initrd and command line vary between kernel versions.

Note that TPM measurements are mostly independent from UEFI "Secure Boot". The Secure Boot state and configuration is measured into PCR 7, but that's about the extent of their interaction.